# Django Rest Framework 3.0 : IntegrityError Exception Value: (1048, "Column' cannot be null")

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have defined models as below

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
    class Customer(models.Model):    
        cust_firstname=models.TextField(max_length=50)
        cust_lastname=models.TextField(max_length=50)
        cust_company=models.TextField(max_length=100)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        cust_contact_number = models.IntegerField()
        cust_email = models.TextField(max_length=100)
        cust_address=models.TextField(max_length=200,default=None)

        def __unicode__(self):
           return self.cust_firstname

    class Employee(models.Model):
        employee_firstname = models.TextField(max_length=50)
        employee_lastname = models.TextField(max_length=50)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        employee_contact_number = models.IntegerField()
        employee_email = models.TextField(max_length=100)
        employee_designation = models.TextField(max_length=50)
        employee_address=models.TextField(max_length=200, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.employee_firstname

    class ProjectDetails(models.Model): 
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
        employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee)
        project_name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
        project_startdate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, default=None)
        project_status = models.TextField(default="Initial")
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

and my serializer is as shown below

```
     from ProjectTemplate.models import Customer, Employee, ProjectDetails
     from rest_framework import serializers

       class CustomerSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         class Meta:
         model=Customer
         fields =   ('id','cust_firstname','cust_lastname','cust_company','created_at','updated_at','cust_contact_number','cust_email','cust_address')

    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

       class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
         model=Employee
          fields =   ('id','employee_firstname','employee_lastname','created_at','updated_at','employee_contact_number','employee_email','employee_designation','employee_address')

    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

class ProjectDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#customer = CustomerSerializers(read_only=True)
#employee = EmployeeSerializer(read_only=True)
    customer = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='cust_firstname', read_only=True)
    employee = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='employee_firstname', read_only=True)
class Meta:
        model = ProjectDetails
        fields =       ('id','project_name','project_startdate','created_at','updated_at','project_status','customer','employee')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

and my POST method in the view is

```
    from django.http import Http404
    from ProjectTemplate.models import ProjectDetails, Customer, Employee
    from ProjectTemplate.serializers import ProjectDetailsSerializer,               CustomerSerializers, EmployeeSerializer
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework import status



class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProjectDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectDetailsSerializer


def perform_create(self, serializer):
    custid = self.request.data.get("customer_id")
    empid = self.request.data.get("employee_id")
    serializer.save(
        customer=Customer.objects.get(pk=custid),
        employee=Employee.objects.get(pk=empid))

def perform_update(self, serializer):       
    custid = self.request.data.get("customer_id")
    empid = self.request.data.get("employee_id")
    serializer.save(
        customer=Customer.objects.get(pk=custid),
        employee=Employee.objects.get(pk=empid))

def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

When i try to post a request i get an integrity error.
the code does not save the object since it is not getting the customer_id foreign key value. Please find the screen shot attached. can some sone help me to know whats wrong in the serializer method.[image]

Comment: i have renamed im using Django rest framework 3.0

Comment: What data are you posting to this view?

Comment: JSON  request im posting it from chrome postman developer tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because when you are saving the `serializer` the `customer` and `employee` are not set on the `instance`. Setting these values on the `serializer` itself won't have any effect at all. You have to pass these additional values in the `save` method of the `serializer`.

Additionally, I would suggest that you override the `perform_create` method and not the `post` method:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    custid = self.request.data.get("customer_id")
    empid = self.request.data.get("employee_id")
    serializer.save(
        customer=Customer.objects.get(pk=custid),
        employee=Employee.objects.get(pk=empid)
    )
```

This is straight from the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods):

> The following methods are provided by the mixin classes, and provide **easy overriding of the object save or deletion behavior**.
>
> - `perform_create(self, serializer)` - Called by `CreateModelMixin` when saving a new object instance.

---

**UPDATE** on using [`ModelViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset):

You don't need to use `APIView` but you could use `ModelViewSet` for different operations e.g. `list`, `retrieve`, `create` etc.

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ProjectDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectDetailsSerializer

    # now you can add your perform_create here
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        custid = self.request.data.get("customer_id")
        empid = self.request.data.get("employee_id")
        serializer.save(
            customer=Customer.objects.get(pk=custid),
            employee=Employee.objects.get(pk=empid)
        )
```